# Can I get a New Event button in Open Activities to return to the Event instead of the account?

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking, redirect, custom-url

I am trying to get a New Event Button in Open Activities on the Account to return to the Event in question after save.

I have created a "New Meeting Event" List Button which inserts a specific Record Type

```
/00U/e?who_id={!Account.Id}&what_id= 
{!Account.Id}&RecordType=0122100000005s5&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&saveURL=%2F{!Event.Id}
```

This results in the following URL when pressing the button:

```
/00U/e? who_id=00121000001pEdZ&what_id=00121000001pEdZ&RecordType=0122100000005s5&retURL
 =%2F00121000001pEdZ&saveURL=%2F
```

Note that the event ID is blank on the saveURL and a save ends up directing me to the Home page. Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can resolve issue if you remove &saveURL=%2F ending from your link. At least this work for me.
Just use

```
/00U/e?who_id={!Account.Id}&what_id= 
{!Account.Id}&RecordType=0122100000005s5&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}
```

Comment: /00U/e?who_id={!Account.Id}&what_id= 
{!Account.Id}&RecordType=0122100000005s5&retURL=%2F{!Account.Id} Returns to the account and not the event. Unsure if this is relevant but I am in a Wealth Management Org using Person Accounts, winter 16 release.